# Accidentally modified a file in gnuplot and closed the file. Is there any way to restore the file?

Tags: terminal, gnuplot, restore, undo, undo-redo

I didn't realize that gnuplot can modify files and somehow changed a file that represents a weeks-long simulation.  I can't re-run the simulation and it's so large that there's no back-up.  I expect I'm doomed but thought I would ask if anyone knows of a way to undo the change and restore the file.  I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What does "somehow" mean? What did you actually do with gnuplot? Anyway,I fear that overwritten is overwritten unless your operating system (what is it actually?) has a backup mechanism and the original file is still somewhere in a "cache" folder.

Comment: I over-wrote data in the file when trying to plot a running average.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Gnuplot` does not make a backup before overwriting the designated output.